# Backbone events being fired on every button in the View?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a pretty simple Backbone.View seen here:

var app = app || {};

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  app.HomeView = Jr.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#home-view').html()),
    events: {
      'click #show-workouts-list': 'showWorkouts',
      "click #clear-localstorage": "clearLocalStorage"
    },
    initialize: function() {

    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template({ numberOfWorkouts: this.collection.length }));
      return this;
    },
    showWorkouts: function() {
      console.log('show workouts');
      var workoutsView = new app.WorkoutsView();
      app.Router.renderView(workoutsView);

      /* cleanup the view after we move away */
      this.remove();
    },
    clearLocalStorage: function(event) {
      console.log('cleared localstorage');
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  });

})(Zepto);
```

And the template:

```
<script id="home-view" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <header class="bar-title">
   <div class="header-animated">
     <h1 class="title">robus</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content content-padded">
    <ul class="list inset">
      <li>
        <a id="show-workouts-list" href="#workouts">
          <strong>Workouts</strong>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <span class="count">{{ numberOfWorkouts }}</span
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="clear-localstorage" class="button button-block button-negative">Clear localStorage</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

When I click on the "clear localStorage" button, the `showWorkouts()` function is also being fired, even though I'm declaring specific IDs in the event block. The `clearLocalStorage()` function gets fired as well.

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may simply be that you have a span tag that is improperly closed:

`<span class="count">{{ numberOfWorkouts }}</span`